# Why does this piece of code repeat itself?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

The following code snippet was found on

http://www.jchapron.com/2015/08/14/getting-started-with-redux/

```
import React from 'react';  
import { createStore as initialCreateStore, compose } from 'redux';

export let createStore = initialCreateStore;

if (__DEV__) {  
  createStore = compose(
    require('redux-devtools').devTools(),
    require('redux-devtools').persistState(
      window.location.href.match(/[?&]debug_session=([^&]+)\b/)
    ),
    createStore
  );
```

Why does the author import `initialCreateStore` as `createStore` and then reassign that same result to `createStore`

Wont just importing `createStore` from the beginning do the same thing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does the author import `initialCreateStore` as `createStore`?

He doesn't, it's the other way round. The `import` is creating an `initialCreateStore` binding in the module scope.

> Why does he then reassign that same result to `createStore`?

Because of verbosity. He wants to be explicit that it's only the initial value of the exported binding.

> Wont just importing `createStore` from the beginning do the same thing?

No, because in ES6 imported bindings are "immutable" - they can change (if they change in the module that exported them), but they cannot be assigned to in the importing module.
The author does however want to overwrite the `createStore` with his own in case `__DEV__` is present, so he does need to declare his own binding with `export let createStore`.

Comment: Thanks very much, that makes sense. I am still trying to get used to this syntax :)